# Edge colors in barplots based on hue/palette

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to set the edge color for the `barplot` created using `seaborn`. The issue seems to be when I use hue parameter.

Instead of having a **separate color** for each individual bar, the edgecolor parameter applies the color to the whole hue/group.

Reproducing the issue via this simple example.

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
t_df = tips.groupby(['day','sex'])['tip'].mean().reset_index()
```

Hence t_df will be ,

[image]

```
clrs = ["#348ABD", "#A60628"]
t_ax = sns.barplot(x='day',y='tip',hue='sex',data=t_df,alpha=0.75,palette= sns.color_palette(clrs),edgecolor=clrs)
plt.setp(t_ax.patches, linewidth=3)   # This is just to visualize the issue.
```

The output this gives ,

[image]

What I want is the blue bar should be having blue edge color and same for red.  What code change would this require ?

Comment: You should probably file a bug report.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is somewhat hacky but it gets the job done:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.patches

# grab everything that is on the axis
children = t_ax.get_children()

# filter for rectangles
for child in children:
    if isinstance(child, matplotlib.patches.Rectangle):

        # match edgecolors to facecolors
        clr = child.get_facecolor()
        child.set_edgecolor(clr)
```

#### EDIT:

@mwaskom's suggestion is obviously much cleaner. For completeness:

```
for patch in t_ax.patches:
    clr = patch.get_facecolor()
    patch.set_edgecolor(clr)
```

Comment: You can also get at the bars more directly in the `ax.patches` list.

Comment: @Paul The way you describe works. @mwaskom - so there is no way available in `sns.barplot` method to do this ?

Comment: Thanks, @mwaskom, I always forget that you can get the patches directly. Added your solution.